# Trigger - How do I get an id for a custom object by matching two fields

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, compile-error

When products are inserted, I want to update a lookup field (`Product_Pillar__c`) which looks up to the `Product_Manager__c` object. I need to query the `Product Manager` object to get id when the `Product2.Family` matches `Product_Manager__c.Name`.

My error is:

> Triggers/ProductFam.trigger: expecting a colon, found 'Product2.Family' (Line: 6, Column: 121) but I don't know how helpful that is

Here is my code below:

```
trigger ProductFam on Product2 (after insert) {

  List<Product2> prodToUpdate = new List<Product2>();

    for (Product2  p : [SELECT Id,Name,Family,Product_Pillar__c,(Select Name,ID from Product_Manager__c pm WHERE pm.Name = Product2.Family) FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]) {
        p.Product_Pillar__c = pm.pmid;
        prodToUpdate.add(a);
    }
    update prodToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: There's no question here. Can you edit this and describe what the problem is and what you'd like to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take this sub-query and assume that you are trying to map `Product2.Family` to `Product_Manager__c.Name`:

```
Select Name,ID from Product_Manager__c pm WHERE pm.Name = Product2.Family
```

The very immediate compile fail is because when you merge `Apex` variables into your `SOQL`, you need to use a colon character (`:`) before the variable name:

```
WHERE Name = :Product2.Family
```

However, you're headed down entirely the wrong path. Fixing that compile fail will just lead you down a long string of further problems.

From how you've described your schema, it seems that `Product_Manager__c` is the parent object here, not the child. That's far from the only thing wrong with your code. The most basic fixes involve:

- Migrate to a `before` trigger. As per the [`Apex Developer Guide`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm):

  > There are two types of triggers:
  >
  > - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
  > - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.
- Iterate your trigger records to collect all `Family` values involved.
- Query the `Project_Manager__c` object directly and map by `Name`.
- Find the relevant `Project_Manager__c` for each `Product2` record.

You should also look into trigger handler and service patterns, but that's somewhat outside the scope of this question. Here's the basic pattern you should follow:

**Trigger**

```
trigger Product2 on Product2 (before insert)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            ProductService.findProductManager(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public with sharing class ProductService
{
    public static void findProductManager(List<Product2> records)
    {
        Set<String> families = new Set<String>();
        for (Product2 record : records) families.add(record.Family);

        Map<String, Product_Manager__c> managers = new Map<String, Product_Manager__c>();
        for (Product_Manager__c manager : [
            SELECT Name FROM Product_Manager__c
            WHERE Name IN :families
        ]) managers.put(manager.Name, manager);

        for (Product2 record : records)
            if (managers.containsKey(record.Family))
                record.Product_Pillar__c = managers.get(record.Family).Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. It worked, but more importantly, I learned a lot from your answer.  I really don't know how to express how helpful this was and I really appreciate your time on explaining the concept.

Comment: @disasterlooms If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: @disasterlooms That's how we show appreciation in these parts. :) Welcome to SFSE. Might be worth taking a moment to scroll through the [tour].